# How do I point to the applications folder?

Tags: ruby, macos, rake

How do I point to the applications folder in rake?  I tried

```
task :md do     
mkdir File.join(File.expand_path("~/Applications/My\ App/Folder1/Folder2"),"Folder3") 
end
```

`puts` shows that I'm taken to `/users/me/Applications` instead of my main Applications folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the `~` to be:

```
/Applications/My\ App/Folder1/Folder2
```

`~` specifies the users home directory, which is not where applications are normally stored.